# Haskell Stack: The following package identifiers were not found in your indices

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build a haskell project using stack. After running `stack setup`, which seems to installs GHC fine, I ran `stack build` and encountered the following error:

```
Didn't see language-c-0.5.1 in your package indices.
Updating and trying again.
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading timestamp
No updates to your package index were found
Update complete
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: language-c-0.5.1
Possible candidates: language-c-0.5.0.
```

I'm not sure why that is. Running `stack ghci` also gives the exact same message. (But running `stack ghc` outputs `ghc: no input files` as expected).

I have tried removing `~/.stack/indices`, but that didn't fix the problem.

Here's my stack version information

```
⇒  stack --version
Version 1.6.3, Git revision b27e629b8c4ce369e3b8273f04db193b060000db (5454 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
```

The local GHC version is 7.10.3

Here's my stack.yaml, excluding some commented sections

```
# Specifies the GHC version and set of packages available (e.g., lts-3.5, nightly-2015-09-21, ghc-7.10.2)
resolver: lts-6.12

# Local packages, usually specified by relative directory name
packages:
- .
- ./compdata
- ./comptrans
- ./compstrat
- location:
    git: git@github.com:jkoppel/language-java.git
    commit: 68e71843294b233c36b3cbe52d9b1e35a5898997
  extra-dep: true
- location:
    git: git@github.com:dvekeman/language-c.git
    commit: caf4888d6c32d97f57d5107db3369e90b5d2649e
  extra-dep: true
- location:
   git: git@github.com:bjpop/language-python.git
   commit: 9269c77ca67c52280314a122cae1b3fa1a044168
  extra-dep: true

# Packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps: [language-lua-0.10.0, language-python-0.5.4, language-java-0.2.8, language-javascript-0.6.0.9, language-c-0.5.1, language-dot-0.1.0, fgl-5.5.3.0]

# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags: {}

# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs: []
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the versions on hackage - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c - 0.5.1 doesn't exist.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18549599)

Comment: Umair, I disagree.  This concisely answers the question in a way that is clearly generalizable.  Concision is not indicative of it not including essential parts of the answer.  It is just indicative that this problem is *super* trivial.  Also, the linked page is stable w.r.t. this question.  So yeah, please consider your answer policing more carefully in the future.

Comment: this link may answer OP's question but the reason I marked this answer is because there is no detail with the link. If you think that this link will answer the question then I believe you should have given up some details too even in your own words. From the first look at the answer it looks like it's just another answer with the link only. :)

Comment: "0.5.1 doesn't exist" is in fact the entire answer. The link simply provides evidence of that fact. mgsloan is correct.